# construct inner join with AND using Knex.js in Node application

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js

Is ti possible to write a join similar to this `SQL` join using `knex.js` in a `Node` application?

```
INNER JOIN member_staff ON members.id = member_staff.member_id AND staff.id = member_staff.staff_id
```

I assume it would look something like this(although this doesn't work and I can't find any docs which explain how to do what I want):

```
.innerJoin('member_staff', 'members.id', 'member_staff.member_id').onAnd('staff.id', 'member_staff.staff_id')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
.innerJoin('member_staff', function() {
    this.on('member.id', 'member_staff.member_id')
    .andOn('staff.id', 'member_staff.staff_id');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `onIn`?

`.onIn('contacts.id', [7, 15, 23, 41])`

OnAnd doesn't exist.

You could also use `onExists`

```
knex.select('*').from('users').join('contacts', function() {
    this.on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.id').onExists(function() {
        this.select('*').from('accounts').whereRaw('users.account_id = accounts.id');
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks but neither are what I'm looking for.